# OpenGL ES: What does "Vector-wise uniform limits" mean?

Tags: graphics, 3d, opengl-es

In the Appendix F of OpenGL ES 3.0.6 Specification, it is mentioned "Vector-wise uniform limits" as a not recommended legacy feature.

I don't know what it means and cannot find the explanation. Could someone help me to explain this terminology?

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean that the constants `MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS` and `MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` still exist in GLES 3, but that newer code should use `MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` or `MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` instead.